# I cant select data from database with inner join using mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I cant select data from database .

My table structrure is given below

customer table

```
id      name
10      geetha
```

customer country table

```
id    cust_id  country

1       10      6
2       10      16
```

I got the result like these way

```
customer name      country


geetha             6
geetha             16
```

But i want  to get the one customer data only one time ie with out repeating.

```
customer name      country


geetha             6
```

my query is

```
SELECT customer.name,customer.id,customer_country.country_id, customer_country.cust_id
    FROM customer
    INNER JOIN customer_country on customer.id = customer_country.cust_id
```

Comment: And do you want the first or last inserted country-id?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have duplicates in the `customer_country` table, then you need to choose one of them.  Here is one method using `max()`:

```
select c.name, max(cc.country_id)
from customer c inner join
     customer_country cc
     on c.id = cc.cust_id
group by c.name;
```

If you want all of them in a list, use `group_concat()`:

```
select c.name, group_concat(cc.country_id) as countries
from customer c inner join
     customer_country cc
     on c.id = cc.cust_id
group by c.name;
```

Answer (score 0):

For first record only, apply to the end: limit 1

```
    SELECT customer.name,customer.id,customer_country.country_id,
    customer_country.cust_id from customer 
    inner join customer_country on customer.id= customer_country.cust_id limit 1
```

Answer (score 0):

try this i add distinct before customer_country.cust_id

```
SELECT customer.name,customer.id,customer_country.country_id, distinct customer_country.cust_id
FROM customer
INNER JOIN customer_country on customer.id = customer_country.cust_id
```